# Cassandra, Xen, and ballooning VHDs

Tags: cassandra, virtual-machine, xen, vhd

My group has several VMs running Cassandra, hosted on a decently powerful physical machine. Each VM was given a dynamically-sized VHD.

Not long after we enabled incremental backups and began taking snapshots, we noticed the VMs expanded to fill all available space, before reporting disk errors and crashing. Currently, the VHDs are still taking up all available space on the system.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior, and is there a way to shrink the VHD back to a reasonable size?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation but not with VHDs. In our situation, our backups directory for system and opscenter keyspaces was getting real huge. When we use the "nodetool clearsnapshot" command, it does not clear the incremental_backups directory. That has to be taken care of with rm -rf.  The backups directory  was getting huge because of running frequent repairs.